# Borders and vertical dividers

Tags: css

I want to create some kind of different vertical dividers than usual ones. Instead of using the classic css border properties, how may I implement something like the dividers at the bottom(blue footer) in the following page: https://www.ote.gr/en/web/guest/consumer. I think this must be a picture. If so,any idea where to find some similar pictures?
Thank you very much

Comment: Borders are probably your best option of doing this - why use an image? I would suggest `<vr>` if it existed.

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to ask proper questions.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Photoshop it? And this is their image BTW. https://www.ote.gr/ote-corporate-theme/images/divider.png

Comment: You're asking where to find images? Your best bet is to create your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you gave does indeed use a picture, which is probably the easiest way for this effect.

I would strongly advise you to learn to work with Chrome Inspector or Firebug. This would show you the following:
[image]

And this would even learn you the image can be found at https://www.ote.gr/ote-corporate-theme/images/divider.png

I would advise you to create your own image though. Shouldn't be that hard...